# Find the average of a given set of numbers where the length of the set varies

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to find the average of given sets of numbers of varying length in R.

The data I have looks like this:

```
    company_name  marketcap  date
    A             100023     01-01-2000
    A             100234     02-01-2000
    A             108332     03-01-2000
    A
    .
    .
    A             112334     31-12-2000
    B              24342     01-01-2000
    B              25345     02-01-2000
.
.
```

There are hundred such companies. I want to calculate average value of marketcap for each company.

Output should look something like this (each marketcap value is an average rather than a set of numbers)

```
    company_name   marketcap  
    A              1023452   
    B               243425
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `aggregate` from `base R` to get the `mean` of 'marketcap' grouped by 'company_name'

```
aggregate(marketcap ~ company_name, df1, FUN = mean)
```

Comment: get the Error in aggregate.data.frame(., company_name ~ nse_market_cap, FUN = mean) : 
  'by' must be a list

Comment: @sylvestermarx  sorry , a typo.  I forgot the dataset object identifier `df1`,  Updated the code

Comment: thanks akrun!!! I got required result.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use the aggregation/group-by of the **data.table** library as:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(your_data_frame)
dt[, .(marketcap = mean(marketcap)), by = company_name)]
```